# The program can't start because SqlSetupBootstrapper.dll is missing, but it is not missing?

Tags: sql-server, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2016, but when I click the setup.exe file I get the message `The program can't start because SqlSetupBootstrapper.dll is missing` but it is not missing, I can see the file. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Redownload the installation files for SQL Server.
2. Copy the installation folder in your machine.
3. Launch the setup

Answer (score 0):

probably you are trying to install through ISO file.
First extract the ISO file in your computer, then launch the setup from that.